# Cross compiling ros for ARM using windows

Tags: robotic-arm, cross-compiling, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I would like to know if it is possible to cross compile ros for ARM using windows.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47526/cross-compiling-ros-for-arm-using-windows/) by [Mlinky](https://answers.ros.org/users/3529/mlinky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably not a good idea. Cross-compiling is challenging enough even on Ubuntu.

Why make it even harder?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-16**:
Hi . I would like to cross compile ROS on Ubuntu 16.04 ARM , with my host being Ubuntu 16.04 x86. I am new to ROS and is there any procedure I can refer to for doing so? Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-02-16**:
Please open a new question, if you want an answer.